# PHP Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am on Laravel 5.2 , I am trying to run tests for the first time, I know this error is already discussed on SO, but I couldn't find any answer..

I run:

```
php artisan make:test TerritoryTest
```

then, in the project root:

```
phpunit
```

But, I got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TestCase' not found in /share/tests/TerritoryTest.php on line 8
```

So, who can help?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer, first:

In the `composer.json` I had to add `"tests/TestCase.php"` at:

```
"autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
```

Then, I had manually added the TestCase.php in tests folder:

```
class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help someone..